# What is this design pattern, and what are its disadvantages?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have been working on a large project for about a year now and recently I have started using a new pattern for displaying data.

**Background**

I have many derived classes wrapping data in 1:1 linked sql tables with their appropriate base classes. My goal was to keep any and all display code unlined from the business logic, and any and all SQL/business logic away from the display code. I think this is good practice in my case, making the code more modular and allowing different display mediums to be introduced. One of the issues I ran into, was it would be more logical for the data classes to have generic display functions, where the actual display medium (html, json, xml) may be added later. I have some recursive drawing functions in some of the classes that would make excluding the draw function quite difficult. My first thought was to create another derived class for each type I would like to display that simply implements the display function in the desired way, but that breaks another pattern I am following. I use factory methods to instantiate most of these classes. Provided an ID, it fetches meta-data from the database so it know which table and which corresponding class it should be linked to. So, in this case, I would need to know what I type am displaying as (HTML, JSON, etc..) before I instantiate it, which also wont work in my case as it would break the factories.

**My solution**

I created a static class that contains "displayer" functions for each display medium. I am utilizing the class as more of a container at this point. The functions in this "dispalyer" class return an anonymous function that takes an instance of the desired class to display. It returns whatever string of displayable data it builds from the objects members. This way I can call `.display()` on any of my classes, and simply pass it a displayer of the desired type: `page->display(PageDisplayer::asHTML());`

I think it looks clean, and allows logic to be separated from display code, while keeping the specific display code in one organized area.

Below is a really simple example, excluding all the factory methods and levels of inheritance I am dealing with.
(This code is subject to errors, I did not write this in a working environment - it may not "compile")

**Main logic/model**

```
<?php
class UserData {
    private $ID;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($ID, $name) {
        $this->ID = $ID;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public getID() {
        return $this->ID;
    }

    public getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function display($displayer) {
        return $dispalyer($this);
    }
}
?>
```

**The displayer Class**

```
<?php
class UserDataDispalyer {

    static function asHTML() {
        return function($userData) {
            $out = '<div id="' . $userData->getID() . '">';
            $out .= $userData->getName();
            $out .= "<div>";
            return $out;
        }
    }

    static function asJSON() {
        return function($userData) {
            return json_encode(array("ID" => $userData->getID(), "name" => $userData->getName()));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here is what the front-end rendering code could look like

**HTML page**

```
<html>

<?php
$userData = new UserData(12345, "John");
echo $userData->display(UserDataDispalyer::asHTML());
?>

</html>
```

**JSON API**

```
<?php
$userData = new UserData(12345, "John");
echo $userData->display(UserDataDispalyer::asJSON());
?>
```

**The Question**

Lastly, My actual question: Is this a known design pattern? Are there any major drawbacks I am missing? Is there a reason I should not use this?

Comment: Hmmm.. this might be better on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or even [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Looks a lot like standard [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), except with slightly different interaction between the three and not as clear divide between business logic and representation.

Comment: It reminds me of State or Strategy, but they don't usually involve the passing of function parameters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code architecture, which belongs to [programmers.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a name for what you're doing and there really shouldn't be. This is a text-book example of when to use an interface and [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

The drawback of your method is that you could pass an arbitrary function to `display` and get all sorts of errors. Using an interface, you make sure that the only argument passed to `display` is of a certain type (below, the type is UserFormatter).

Here's an example of the same code, but using an interface.

```
interface UserFormatter {
  public function get($user);
}

public HTMLFormatter implements UserFormatter {
  public function get($user) {
    return "<div id=\"{$user->getID()}\">{$user->getName()}</div>";
  }
}

public JSONFormatter implements UserFormatter {
  public function get($user) {
    return json_encode(array('ID'   => $user->getID(),
                             'name' => $user->getName()));
  }
}
```

In your `userData` class, you will then have

```
public function display(UserFormatter $formatter) {
        return $formatter->get($this);
    }
```

Also, your `userData` class should be named `UserData`. Classes are always in CamelCase.

Comment: Sounds right to me. Thanks for the explanation and tips. (also fixed userData -> UserData. thats what I get for not checking my work)